# Error uploading data:The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I trying to upload image over AWS S3 Bucket using react native platform but i am getting Error uploading data:  Error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Have any one tried to upload images

JavaScript Code to upload Images over AWS S3

```
var uniqueFileName = image.fileName;
console.log("File Name",uniqueFileName)
var bodyData = image.data;
console.log("File Json",bodyData)
var filetype= image.type;
console.log("File Type",filetype)
var AWS3 = require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native');
AWS3.config.update({
         "accessKeyId": AWS.accessKeyId, 
         "secretAccessKey":  AWS.secretAccessKey,
         "region": "us-east-1"
});
var s3 = new AWS3.S3();
var params = {
      Bucket: AWS.bucketName ,
      Key: uniqueFileName,
      ContentType: filetype,
      Body: bodyData,
      ContentEncoding: 'base64'
};        
s3.upload(params, function (err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Successfully uploaded data");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: hey did you solve this?, how you did please help by pasting solution to your answer so we can get the idea